# How to downgrade react-router-dom version to v5.2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

[How to downgrade react-router-dom version to v5.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb68H.png)

Comment: Try `npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0`. If you are using yarn, try `yarn upgrade react-router-dom@5.2.0`

Comment: May want to also save that version to your dependencies so you can "lock" it to v5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a documentation provided by react-router to upgrade or downgrade the react-router version : https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md
or use this npm command:

```
npm install <package>@<version>
npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

*Package version 5.2.3 doesn't exist.*

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I had the same issue, version 5.2.3 don't work with me so I tried 5.2.0 and it working, thanks.